# Which Facebook account to use for creating Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been working on developing a Facebook App for sometime now. We are ready to setup the App for PROD environment. I am having trouble determining which Facebook account to use for creating the Facebook App, as Facebook does not allow creating Facebook account for a company. I am the developer of the App so I will need administrator right but I think its not wise to create the App using my personal Facebook account as the employees may change but the App stays with the company and another employee may need administrator right going forward. What is the standard way of setting up the Facebook account and App in such scenario?
Any help / guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is the only way that is actually allowed: You have to use your own account. In addition, just add another account as Admin, a colleague who can take over if you are not in the company anymore or if your account gets blocked/hacked/whatever. I highly suggest using 2-step-verification in the account settings, it is called "Login Approval" on Facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, luschn. That seems to be the only feasible way, but I still have trouble wrapping my head around this solution as it doesn't sound 'industry-standard' to use employee's personal Facebook account to build a company product. Wish Facebook had something similar to "Pinterest for Business".